# USE and UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with MS SQL Server and I am trying to gather informations from a few different databases and I need the results in one table.

```
USE [1st Database]

   select smthing

USE [2nd Database]

   select smthing

USE [3rd Database]
```

And UNION ALL somewhere between. I cannot find any solution right now.

Comment: Use 3 part naming the reference the objects.

Comment: NB: You don't have to switch context with `USE` in order to reference other dbs...

Comment: This way ? `SELECT [1st Database]..smthing UNION ALL [2nd Database]..smthing UNION ALL [3rd Database]..smthing`

Comment: Yeah but i have smthing like 150+ data bases and i didnt want to write
Select [database name] smthing 150 times, because i use this sql on master base level

Comment: You can use Synonyms. You create a Synonym for each table in a single database (you can do you with repeatable DDL commands) and then create a view with all the UNION. But it is an hugly design. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-synonym/

Comment: How is adding `USE DATABASE` to all of your queries *less* work than using a 3 part naming convention? Surely it's more work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference the database name along with table :

```
select t.col1, t.col2, . . . 
from <db-name>.<schema>.<tablename> t union all
select t.col1, t.col2, . . . 
from <db-name>.<schema>.<tablename> t;
```

This needs to access to the all databases you included in the `select` statement.

Comment: So i have to write it 150 times ;d because its amount of my data bases

Comment: @JakubStankiewicz. . . Yes, you have no options do that, because you don't know which columns you want to display. Tables have columns very.

Comment: @JakubStankiewicz. . . We can use Dynamic `SQL`, but that should be fixed columns or know columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can run something like this, copy and paste the result in SSMS, then remove the last `UNION ALL` manually before executing the generated rows:

```
SELECT
      CONCAT('SELECT TOP 10 make_id, make_name FROM ', db.name, '.dbo.[Makes] UNION ALL')
FROM  sys.databases AS db
WHERE db.name LIKE 'MyCarsDBs%';
```